# On AEM - Publish option do not work in Chrome and Firefox on Windows 8 & 10

Tags: adobe, aem

The “Publish” and “Publish later” options do not work/clickable-but-no-actions in Chrome (latest version 66) and Firefox (latest version 59) on AEM 6.3.1 CFP2 on Windows 8 and 10

The same works on Edge browser on Windows 10 and on all browsers on Mac.

We tried to disable all extensions on the browsers and try, but it did not help. The same worked on Windows 2016 Server though.

Anyone came across this?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of testing, we identified the root cause.

**Reason for the issues**
The default setting in Chrome is "Automatic."
If the user touches on the touchscreen then it will process the action, but if they click with a mouse it will not respond. And this only happens with touch events on a touch-enabled Windows PC.
AEM is listening for the wrong event and it cannot be reproduced on a desktop PC or laptop with no touch screen because the browser will automatically disable the touch events feature anyway.
The user has to either disable the touch events feature of the browser or they can use their touch screen and physically tap on the publish button.

**Resolution**

- Tested this on AEM 6.3, SP1, CFP 2

**On Chrome**

- Type chrome://flags/#touch-events in your browser
- Please set it to Disabled
- Select Relaunch Now

  [image]

**On Firefox**

- Type about:config in your browser and click the accept button
- Search for dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled
- If it is set to 0, please set it to 2

  [image]